# Refresh a BarChart after adding a BarSeries

Tags: apache-flex, bar-chart

first question here.
I have a BarChart showing several normal bars and a BarSeries, like this:

```
<mx:BarChart id="barchart" dataProvider="{model.myList}" type="clustered">
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis autoAdjust="true"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="name"/>
    </mx:verticalAxis>
    <mx:series>
        <mx:BarSeries dataProvider="{model.myList}" xField="myValue"/>
    </mx:series>
</mx:BarChart>
```

When a user clicks on a button, i need to calculate some values, put them on the "myCalculatedValue" and add another BarSeries as a comparison. I'm doing this:

```
var barSerie:BarSeries = new BarSeries();
barSerie.dataProvider = model.myList;
barSerie.xField = "myCalculatedValue";
barchart.series.push(barSerie);
```

But the BarChart does not change at all. Is there some way to refresh the chart after adding the new BarSeries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to use this code:

```
var barSerie:BarSeries = new BarSeries();
barSerie.dataProvider = model.myList;
barSerie.xField = "myCalculatedValue";
var allSeries:Array = barchart.series;
allSeries.push(barSerie);
barchart.series = allSeries;
```

---

The LONG answer, to give you an understanding of how this works:

The way flex knows when to refresh a ui component that is data backed, such as a chart, is on the `function set dataProvider` property, or equivalent (in this case `series`).

Here is the code from `mx.charts.chartClasses.ChartBase`:

```
public function set series(value:Array /* of Series */):void
{
    value = value == null ? [] : value;
    _userSeries = value;

    var n:int = value.length;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (value[i] is Series)
        {
            (value[i] as Series).owner = this;                
        }
    }

    invalidateSeries();
    invalidateData();
    legendDataChanged();
}
```

Notice that the relevant "invalidate" methods are called at the end of the set method.
If you say `barChart.series.push(x)`, the `set series` method is never called, only the `getter`.  Therefore in order to force the chart to know there was a change to the series, you need to assign a new value to the series.

It is worth pointing out that even assigning the series to itself will cause an invalidate, although it isn't good coding
`barChart.series = barChart.series`

Answer (score 0):

Flex is communicating with the server remotely, correct? You probably need to make another explicit call to the app controller that is housing flex.

Comment: Yes, flex is communicating remotely. But even if i'm getting the new data from a server or locally, i think the problem is client-side.. i need some kind of refresh() or redraw() after i add the new BarSeries.